# Merge 2 pandas dictionary columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe simplified here with 3 columns.

```
| id | channels | facebookCount |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 0  | {'channel': 'Google', 'count': 0.0}    | 3 |
| 1  | {'channel': 'Google', 'count': 4.0}    | 0 |
| 2  | {'channel': 'Google', 'count': 3.0}    | 6 |
```

The `channels` column was a simple count column like `facebookCount`. However, I transformed into a dictionary using `apply` and `lambda` as such:

```
        data_df["channels"] = data_df["googleCount"].apply(
           lambda x: {} if x is None else {"channel": "Google", "count": x})
```

How can I construct the channel column so that it has data for both facebook and google so that I have a list containing 2 dictionaries as seen below:

```
| id | channels |
|:---- |:------:|
| 0   | [{'channel': 'Google', 'count': 0.0}, {'channel': 'Facebook', 'count': 3.0}] |
| 1   | [{'channel': 'Google', 'count': 4.0}, {'channel': 'Facebook', 'count': 0.0}] |
| 2   | [{'channel': 'Google', 'count': 3.0}, {'channel': 'Facebook', 'count': 6.0}] |
```

I have tried creating both dictionaries and then setting channel as well as creating one dictionary and then merging the 2 using apply and lambda as well as a helper function as such

```
dict1 = data_df["30DayGoogleCampaignCount"].apply(
    lambda x: {"channel": "Google", "count": x})

data_df["paidMediaChannels"] = data_df["30DayFacebookCampaignCount"].apply(
    lambda x: self.Merge(dict1, {"channel": "facebook", "count": x}))


   def Merge(self, dict1, dict2):
        return(dict2.update(dict1))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `{'channel': 'Google', 'count': 0.0, 'channel': 'Facebook', 'count': 3.0}` is invalid in python. `dict` keys _must_ be unique.

Comment: @HenryEcker I edited the question so that I would be looking to create a list with 2 dictionaries. Thanks!

Comment: @M.Spiller How can I construct the channel column so that it has data for both facebook and google so that I have a list containing 2 dictionaries as seen below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [0, 1, 2],
                   'channels': [{'channel': 'Google', 'count': 0.0},
                                {'channel': 'Google', 'count': 4.0},
                                {'channel': 'Google', 'count': 3.0}],
                   'facebookCount': [3, 0, 6]})

# Create List
df['channels'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: [x['channels'],
               {'channel': 'Facebook',
                'count': x['facebookCount']}],
    axis=1
)
# Drop facebookCount Column
df = df.drop(columns='facebookCount')

print(df.to_string())
```

`df`:

```
   id                                                                    channels
0   0  [{'channel': 'Google', 'count': 0.0}, {'channel': 'Facebook', 'count': 3}]
1   1  [{'channel': 'Google', 'count': 4.0}, {'channel': 'Facebook', 'count': 0}]
2   2  [{'channel': 'Google', 'count': 3.0}, {'channel': 'Facebook', 'count': 6}]
```